# Why is this valid in Strict XHTML 1.0?

Tags: css, validation, xhtml

I am wondering why this is valid in XHTML:

```
<div style="apple: banana">  
<h1 style="text-decoration: line-through;">
```

I thought you need closing /> to be validated in strict XHTML. Please could someone help

Comment: where are you testing?

Comment: Through the validator

Comment: I get 4 errors and 3 warnings if I try that. If I were you, I'd be more concerned about the CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

These fragments have closing tags after the content (i.e. are not self closing) - f/example:

```
<div style="apple: banana">  My content here </div>
```

whereas if you tried with a self-closing tag:

```
<hr align="right"> - wrong
<hr align="right" /> - right
```

P.S. you studying at Newcastle? These code snippets look awfully familiar :p